# How to implement iPhone Contact app edit transition effect?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to reproduce the animation effect that the Contact app uses when switching to edit mode. Specifically I have a number of fields that I'd like to display in a more friendly format, but then expand them into a layout that makes them easier to update or add when in edit mode.

Is this done using core animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No animation is needed. Just monitor when the table view's `editing` property changes (when the Edit button is pressed). Then add code to your delegate methods to compose, draw and indent cells in a different way, when the table view is in editing mode.