# Editing functionality mimicking iOS stock contacts app

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

I am storing a list of contacts in my app in a tableview. When an indiviual contact is selected the app navigates to a static table view with their address and phone number in 2 separate cells. I would like to copy the editing functionality in the default iphone contact app where when edit is pressed these cells transition into textfields.

I was wondering how this is done. Is it a transition to a separate view? Or can this be done with the tableview editing controls?

Comment: This might help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303518/how-to-implement-iphone-contact-app-edit-transition-effect